# Google map is not displaying without form element in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My aspx page content is this

```
<body>
 <div id="mapDiv"></div>
 <form id="form" runat="server"></form>
</body>
```

and in the code-behind I create the script

```
string script = string.Format(@"function initialize() {{
                    var mapOptions = {{
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng({0},{1}),
                    zoom: 8,
                    tilt: 30
                    }};

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), mapOptions);

                {2}                                                        
                }}

                function addInfoWindow(marker, content) {{
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({{
                        content: content
                    }});

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {{
                        if (currentInfoWindow != null) {{
                            currentInfoWindow.close(); 
                        }}

                        infoWindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                        currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
                    }});
                }}                                                          

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
                var currentInfoWindow = null;",
                coordinates[0], coordinates[1], DrawMarkers(groups));

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mapInit", script, true);
```

If the aspx contains the div and the form elements, as it is now, everything works fine. However I have to use a master page with this aspx file. When I change its content accordingly I have to remove the form element, as there is already one in the master file. But when I remove the form element, the map disappears.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in my custom css I had set "height: 100%" and the browser did not like it, although "width: 100%" is fine. So I solved my issue by using

```
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapDiv'); 
var height = Math.max(0, document.documentElement.clientHeight - 110).toString();
mapDiv.setAttribute('style','height: ' + height + 'px');
```